# Question regarding the formal definition of limes Inferior/Superior

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, limsup-and-liminf

I have a question regarding the definitions of limes inferior/superior of a sequence $x_n$.

Limes inferior for example is defined as

$$lim ~ sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n := lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (sup\{x_k |k \ge n\})\in \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\}$$

Now I simply do not understand why the condition $k \ge n$ is needed. Is it meant as the new sequence created by the limes inferior kind of goes ahead of the actual sequence $x_n$ and checks its values in advance?

It really confuses me at the moment.

Thank you very much for your help.
FunkyPeanut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you here an intuitive description as it seems it is what you asked for (I swapped the $n$'s and the $k$'s sorry).

Reason: one of the main ideas is that you want to define a limit which exists (which might be infinity), by defining a $\limsup$ of a sequence you pick the highest point of your sequence as it goes to infiny and therefore you pick a point of your sequence, no mater if you limit exists or not.

An intuitive way to compute is to split the process in two steps:

1. take the collection of all subsequences of the form $X_k=\{x_n\}_{n\geq k}$ $k=1,2,...$. The sup exists for all $X_k$ (note that $\sup_n X_k$ is monotonically decreasing in $k$, and so taking the limit cannot give rise to problems related to oscilating sequences for example).
2. Now  you want to pick the *last* supremum of your sequence (the highest point of your sequence as it goes to infinity) ans so take the limit of $X_k$ in $k$.

The easiest example to see how this can be useful is to take the sequence $\{1,-1,1,-1,1,...\}$.

In your comment you are right to say that a new sequence is created it is the sequence $\{\sup_n\{x_n\}_{n\geq k}\}_{k\geq 1}$